# Sampling from MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

I'm working with the following panel data in a `MultiIndex` pandas `DataFrame` called `df_data`:

```
              y         x
n   time                    
0   0     0.423607 -0.307983
    1     0.565563 -0.333430
    2     0.735979 -0.453137
    3     0.962857  1.671106
1   0     0.772304  1.221366
    1     0.455327 -1.024852
    2     0.864768  0.609867
    3     0.334429 -2.567936
2   0     0.435553 -0.259228
    1     0.221501  0.484677
    2     0.773628  0.650288
    3     0.293902  0.566452
```

`n` indexes an individual (there are 500 of them), `t` indexes time. It's a balanced panel. I would like to create a random sample of `nn=100` individuals with replacement.  Also, if an individual makes it into the random sample, then all 4 time observations  (t=0,1,2,3)  for this individual should be assigned to the sample.

The following line is doing almost what I want:

```
df_sample = df_data.loc[np.random.randint(3, size=100).tolist()]
```

However, it does not sample an individual repeatedly. So if the created list of random variables is say [2, 3, 2, 4, 1, ...] then the third individual (index =2 is the third individual) is only selected once and not twice into the random sample. This means that as soon as the random vector above contains the same individual more than once, I end up with fewer than 100 individuals (with 4 time observations each) in the random sample.
I also tried the `df_data.sample`function, but I doesn't seem to be able to handle the specific multilevel index I have here in the panel.
I could write all kinds of loops to get this done, but I thought there should be a simpler (and faster) way of doing this.
I'm on Python 3.5 and I'm using pandas version 0.17.1.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random (bootstrap) sample from pandas multiindex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731858/how-to-get-a-random-bootstrap-sample-from-pandas-multiindex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to quickly produce the format needed to select with duplicates from a `MultiIndex`:

Sample data:

```
from itertools import product
individuals = list(range(500))
time = (0, 1, 2, 3,)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(individuals, time)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': np.random.random(size=2000), 'B': np.random.random(size=2000)}, index=index)

              A         B
0   0  0.208461  0.842118
    1  0.481681  0.096121
    2  0.420538  0.922363
    3  0.859182  0.078940
1   0  0.171162  0.255883
    1  0.338864  0.975492
    2  0.270533  0.504605
    3  0.691041  0.709189
2   0  0.220405  0.925001
    1  0.811951  0.479795
    2  0.010527  0.534866
    3  0.561204  0.915972
3   0  0.813726  0.083478
    1  0.745100  0.462120
    2  0.189111  0.552039
    3  0.006141  0.622969
```

Combine the result of `np.random.randint` with the `time` values using `product`:

```
sample_ix = np.random.randint(low=0, high=500, size=100)

len(np.unique(sample_ix))

91

sample_multi_ix = list(product(sample_ix, time))

[(55, 0), (55, 1), (55, 2), (55, 3), (254, 0), (254, 1), (254, 2), (254, 3), ...]
```

and select accordingly:

```
sample = df.loc[sample_multi_ix, :]
sample.info()

MultiIndex: 400 entries, (55, 0) to (135, 3)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    400 non-null float64
B    400 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 9.4+ KB
```

If you want a unique `sample` `index`, you can add:

```
sample.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(list(range(100)), time))) 

MultiIndex: 400 entries, (0, 0) to (99, 3)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    400 non-null float64
B    400 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, This is a great solution and about 30 times faster than what I cooked up last night. One thing to add to your solution would be to reindex the sample, so that indexes are unique again and some of the pandas functions can be run on it (like OLS, etc.).  Something like this:  
    
    `individualsb = list(range(100))`  and  `indexb = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(individualsb, time)))`  and  `sample = sample.set_index(indexb)`

Comment: You're welcome, updated to get rid of dupes in the `MultiIndex`.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution:

```
subindex = df.index.get_level_values('sub_index')
sample_ids = np.random.choice(subindex, 5, replace=True)
sample = df[subindex.isin(sample_ids)].copy()
```

Comment: Not clear to me if this will sample more than once, given the use of `subindex.isin(sample_ids)`?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, it sort of a compination fo the other answers:

```
subindex = df.index.get_level_values('id')
sample_ids = np.random.choice(subindex, 5, replace=False)
sample = df.loc[sample_ids]
```

I was using a df with an index of ["id", "other"].  It returned a sample of 5 id's and all their associated "others".

Comment: Note that this does not implement sampling with replacement, as requested by the question